# ExoPlayer , Loop Ended/ Started listener for LoopingMediaSource

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am using ExoPlayer for playing video in loop, but before source video is started each loop I need to reset some states of my Layout. I know ExoPlayer is calling onPlayerStateChanged with ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED paramter when video is ended for usual MediaSources, but it is not called for LoopingMediaSource.

```
@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
    if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {
        showControls();
        resetLayoutStates(); //I need it here, even in LoopingMediaSource
    }
    updateButtonVisibilities();
}
```

Does the Exoplayer have any Callback when Source is restarted or ended in loop ? Or does it have any workaround for my situation ?

Comment: Did you find any solution of that?

Answer (score 2):

You can detect that a video loops when the media item changes. This callback will be fired at the end of the media item and give you the new item to play even if that's the same when repeat mode is ONE. You can detect that with the `reason` parameter that tells you why the media changed (either naturally, seeking or looping):

```
override fun onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem: MediaItem?, reason: Int) {
    super.onMediaItemTransition(mediaItem, reason)

    if (reason == Player.MEDIA_ITEM_TRANSITION_REASON_REPEAT) {
        // Reset your state
    }
}
```

You may want to assert that it's the right media item with the given `mediaItem` argument. Especially since it will behave differently whether your repeat mode is ONE or ALL (the media item will be the same for ONE while the first or last item of your timeline for ALL).